# Load testing tools Symfony2 powered website that executes Javascript?

Tags: performance, load-testing

Most of the tools out there do not seem to be interpreting jQuery / Javascript code that is loaded on the page that I want to test. This is however important because that code will, in turn initiate a number of calls to other endpoints in my webapp which adds up to load in a real life scenario.

I've looked at JMeter already and am a bit reluctant to give it a try as the landing page mentions explicitly that it does not do Javascript interpreting at all.

What would be some recommendation of tools that can provide a more accurate measurement of load testing by including Javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

None of the load testing tools really executes JavaScript, they all act on protocol level and JavaScript is being executed by browser.

There are 3 options how you could proceed if you want 100% realistic testing:

1. HP LoadRunner has [TrueClient](https://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/TruClient-in-the-world-of-Load-Testing/ba-p/5927581) protocol which is basically headless browser with JavaScript capabilities.
2. [JMeter with WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) plugin - the way to kick off real browsers from JMeter test
3. [Selenium Grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) (or other way to kick off several Selenium instances at once)

---

All 3 above options are **very** resource intensive, you will required at least 1 CPU core and a couple of gigabytes or RAM for a single browser instance so I would recommend a little bit different approach. JMeter cannot execute JavaScript, but it can execute JavaScript-driven HTTP Requests so create main load using JMeter (or equivalent) and while the load test is running use Selenium to automatically check real browsing experience or [YSLow](http://yslow.org/) to do the same manually.

Answer (score 0):

Load testing tools doesn't execute JavaScript. 
You know which endpoints your JavaScript code is using so just add these endpoints to your JMeter scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The thick client problem has been around since the early 1990s with traditional thick client-server applications.  In fact, the earliest commercial tools were all driving full clients on X Windows before adding API level virtual user capabilities.  On the commercial front this ability to drive full, thick clients is still expressed as GUI virtual users (Mercury/HP/Microfocus LoadRunner, Segue/Borland/Microfocus Silk Performer, Rational/IBM Performance Tester) allowing you to measure the weight between API and user level if needed.

Here is the thing, for a given business process and data set the end client is predictable in its behavior, and in the requests that it makes to the servers that are feeding it data.  There may be a few odd conditions where you need to reproduce an algorithm from JavaScript to C (or even run it directly in some tools) for branching on a type of API/HTTP request, but these are not numerous.